# How to Display first and last name when it's stored in one entity

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    se.socialevent_id,
    title
FROM
    354groupb1.social_event se
    INNER JOIN 354groupb1.executive e  ON se.executive_id = e.executive_id 
    INNER JOIN 354groupb1.member    m  ON e.member_id     = m.member_id 
    INNER JOIN 354groupb1.pnms      pm ON m.net_id        = pm.net_id
WHERE
    se.executive_id IS NOT NULL
    OR
    se.member_id IS NOT NULL;
```

- All of my `first_name` and `last_names` are stored inside the `PNMS` table.
- I want to write a query that will display the `first_name` and `last_name` of anyone who has attended an event.
- However, when I run this query it will only display one person per event.
  *PNMS stands for Potential New Members. All Execs and Members have to have been a PNM
- How do I get more than one member to participate in a social event and more than one executive to run an event

[image]

Comment: What does "PNMS" stand-for or mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "stored in one entity"?

Comment: What does your `social_event` table actually represent? Your DB design only allows for 2 people (a single "executive", whatever that means, and a single "member"), so it's unclear what how DB is meant to work...

Comment: Your data model only allows one member and one executive per social event

Comment: And your query gets the name of the executive of each event.

Comment: You need many-to-many tables between member and social event and between executive and social event